# Bookmarklet help: document.location.hostname

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm using the following javascript in a bookmarklet but it keeps on adding the www. portion, any way for this to work by removing the www portion from the domain? Thanks.

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://siteanalytics.compete.com/'+document.location.hostname));
```

Comment: Where is `www.` added? To the value you get from `document.location.hostname`? If it is part of the hostname then it will be there, of not then not (at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it manually...

```
var noWww = document.location.hostname.replace(/^w{3}\./, '.');
```